# Async-Await deadlock?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asynchronous, async-await, deadlock

I'm routinely getting what I think is a deadlock in my C# code that makes heavy use of async-await. I sometimes get it on this line of code:

```
await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

The thread just blocks indefinitely.

I'm not blocking synchronously anywhere in the code. I use async-await all the way to the top where I initialize a new background thread like so from the entry method which is synchronous:

```
var threads =
new ThreadStart[]
{
    async () => await Run(InitiationDelegate),
                    }.Select(ts =>
    new Thread(ts) { IsBackground = true }
);

foreach(var thread in threads)
{
    thread.Start();
}
```

and Run has the following signature:

```
async Task Run(Func<Task> action)
```

I'm not sure where the deadlocks could be coming from?

Comment: Instead of using threads, why not use Tasks ?

Comment: The deadlock is on the call to the `context` so this is a database issue. Look for a situation in which one thread is selecting and updating data whilst another thread (with a different transactional context) is doing the same thing on the same table/key.

Comment: This appears to have been some temporary glitch with the host machine and not a deadlock issue per se. I might consider deleting the question altogether. @auburg, thanks for the recommendation to use tasks rather than threads.

Comment: @strickt01, I was referring to a threading-deadlock within the application not a database deadlock.